# Animating Touches to Objects - can I get object of touched view?

Tags: javascript, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'd like to get a reference to the object whose view was touched on the iPhone.

I'm probably just approaching this the wrong way so let me try to explain what *trying* to do...

I have various instances of a sub-classed UIImageView with some custom value properties. The user can touch and move them. Depending on where they go I'd like to animate some changes to its *transform* AND update some properties in the ViewController.

I'm currently handling touches in the ViewController (as opposed to each UIImageView) and can't seem to find a reference to the touched object. I can get the view [touch view] but can't get to my custom value properties in my custom object from its view. Am I butchering MVC?!? Should I be handling the touches in each object? But then how would I update the ViewController and manage the animations (which ViewController is doing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I had a problem with how my variables were cast. it works just fine...